# How to fix html border corner slope with css?

Tags: html, css

You can access following code via this link :  [jsfiddle.net/2NPxV](http://jsfiddle.net/2NPxV)

My css code :

```
.custom_content { 
display: block; 
width:200px;
height: 30px; 
margin: 5px 0; 
padding: 0 0;   
border: 1px solid #000000;  }  

.left-border-red
{
border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

My html code :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row custom_content left-border-red">
My content  
</div>  
</div>
```

Result : Please zoom in to image to see top left and bottom left slope areas on rectangle.
http://rasih.net/se/main.png

Problem 1 : Top left corner has slope. I want to fix it.

Problem 2 : Bottom left corner has slope. I want to fix it.

Summary : How can i fix top left and bottom left slope for my output ? I want to keep outer black border and inner red border same time. But i dont want any slope for any corner.

Comment: add this fiddle to your post: http://jsfiddle.net/2NPxV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of border-left you could use the `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements and style that to look how you want

```
.left-border-red:before {
  content:'';
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/valentin/2NPxV/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here, check out this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DX7w8/1/

The only change I made was instead of using the `border-left` property, which causes only that specific segment of the square to be adjusted, I used the `box-shadow` property and manipulated the position such that it appeared to have a red left border, which fills the left side.

I also increased the `padding-left` to 6px so that the text didn't appear to overlap the border.

It's superior because I'm assuming you don't want a black left line showing before your red border.  This is the best way to avoid that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your explanation is amazing. Thank you very much. Both of your answer works enough for me. I specified this sentence in my question - I want to keep outer black border and inner red border same time.- So , Valentin s answer apply with that. But i could not stop myself to say thank you.